# Mostrar mensaje durante la ejecución de una función

Tags: python, tkinter

Utilizando `tkinter` me gustaría mostrar un mensaje por pantalla mientras se está ejecutando una función, la cual tarda mucho en calcular grandes listas de valores, quería hacerlo mostrando el mensaje con `messagebox.showinfo()`  al principio de la función y me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de eliminarlo automáticamente al final de la misma. Gracias.

Comment: Estás usando tkinter? Si es así, podrías agregar la etiqueta tkinter a la pregunta por favor?

Comment: Buen día, no encontré doc. que diga como hacer un cartel de carga con `messagebox.showinfo()`, lo que podes hacer es crear vos un cartel similar con alguna librería para crear GUI. Podes hacer que se muestre al comienzo de la función y que se deshabilite cuando finalice correctamente la misma. Saludos

Comment: Sí, perdón por no especificarlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Propuesta

Que yo sepa no existe ninguna forma de cerrar automáticamente un messagebox. Sin embargo, pude crear un código que abre un Toplevel, ejecuta una función, y luego lo cierra.
Para que la función no bloquee el programa, uso el modulo Threading para crear una nueva tarea que ejecute dicha función.

Aquí te dejo un código que puede servir para poder progresar. Este código abre un toplevel y pasados 3 segundos lo cierra.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Toplevel
import threading
import time

def func():
    # Hago que la función tarde 3 segundos en ejecutarse.
    # Esto es por motivos de prueba, después puedes hacer que esta función haga lo que desees.
    time.sleep(3)

def showinfo(parent=None):
    top = Toplevel(parent)
    top.title("Process")
    # Hago que la ventana sea transient. Esto significa que:
    #     -No se podrá maximizar ni minimizar
    #     -Siempre estará sobre de la ventana padre.
    #     -Si la ventana padre se minimiza, esta ventana también lo hará.
    # Si no quieres que la ventana sea transient, simplemente quita esta linea.
    top.transient(parent)

    # Esto bloquea todas las demás ventanas.
    # Si no quieres que esto suceda, borra esta linea.
    top.grab_set()

    # Ejecuto la función
    func()

    # Una vez la función sea ejecutada, destruyo la ventana.
    top.destroy()

# Creo la ventana raiz
v = Tk()

# Creo la tarea que abrirá el toplevel y ejecutará la función.
threading.Thread(target=showinfo, args=(v,)).start()

# Inicio el mainloop. Sin esto, el programa dará error.
v.mainloop()
```

#### Referencias

- [El modulo Threading](https://rico-schmidt.name/pymotw-3/threading/)
- [Tipos de ventanas](https://python-para-impacientes.blogspot.com/2016/01/tkinter-tipos-de-ventanas.html) (este es el lugar donde encontré mayor información sobre grab_set y transient)

Comment: estas seguro de que se usa tkinter?, lo digo para poder editar la pregunta y añadir la etiqueta

Comment: @Christian Yo no la agregaría la etiqueta hasta que op nos diga si es de tkinter o acepte mi respuesta. Simplemente hice mi respuesta por que me sentí muy seguro de que era de Tkinter. Publicar esta respuesta es un riesgo que decidi tomar. Pero gracias igual c:

Comment: la pregunta necesita 1 voto más y terminará cerrada por el hecho de no especificar el módulo, entre otros detalles. Bueno la dejaré tal y como esta.

Comment: Perdonad, pero si era utilizando tkinter. Gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: @Antonio si la respuesta te sirvió es recomendable aceptarla, por otro lado tu pregunta será reabierta pronto.